# Java - Как преобразовать символы из unicode(10) &#1057 в русские буквы?

Tags: java, html, utf-8, unicode

Есть файл xml, в котором часть полей представлена в виде: Компенсаци

Как в Java сделать преобразование текста из &#1057 (как понимаю это Unicode decimal) в русские буквы?

На чистом коде Java 8, без использования дополнительных библиотек типа apache.

Мой код: по тексту &# заменяем на \u, десятичный код unicode преобразуем в шестнадцатеричный, который преобразуем в символ.

```
String string = "&#1057"; //строка в HTML(dec)
System.out.println("Html(dec): " + string);
string = string.replaceAll("&#", "\\\\u");   
String hex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(string.substring(2, 6)));
string = "\\u0" + hex;
System.out.println("Unicode(hex) :" + string);
// string = "\u0421"; //если напрямую задать текст, то распознается как С
String result = "";
try {
  byte[] charset = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
  result = new String(charset, "UTF-8");
  System.out.println("Text:" + result);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Проблема: на входе &#1057 переводится \u0421 который почему-то не переводится в символ, остается \u0421

Comment: если проблема только в ней то можно заменить на [больщую С](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0421/index.htm), но я подозреваю, что и с другими буквами не ладно, так как эта буква ничем не выделяется среди остальных

Comment: Конечно, проблема не только в одной букве С, эти символы встречаются в тексте. Текст очень большой, из xml файла

Comment: В заголовке XML файла кодировка указана? При чтении файла кодировку указываете или по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1):

Сложность заключается в том что `\u0421` и ему же подобные - это литералы, т.е. они нормально преобразуются в строку сами по себе, но их нельзя составить из двух и более срок, например так: `"\\u0" + hex`

```
System.out.println("\u0421" == "С"); // true
System.out.println("\u" + "0421" == "С"); // error: illegal unicode escape
```

В этой ситуации мне видится самым простым способом - составить словарь и делать замену по нему, если там только русские буквы и немного символов.

Наверняка может существовать способ проще, возможно он тут еще появится, так что этот в качестве запасного выхода, код приведен как есть без возможных оптимизаций:

```
public class Main {
  public static String convAll(String input){
    String ru = "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяѐё";
    String result = new String(input);
    int offset = 1040; // Начало русского алфавита в юникоде
    for (int i=0; i< ru.length(); i++){
        result = result.replaceAll("&#" + (offset + i) + ";",
          Character.toString(ru.charAt(i)));
    }
    // заменяем другие частные случаи  
    result = result.replaceAll("&#1025;", "Ё");
    result = result.replaceAll("&#32;", " ");
    result = result.replaceAll("&quest;", "?");
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String test = "&#1063;&#1090;&#1086;&#32;&#1090;&#1091;&#1090;&#32;&#1087;&#1086;&#1076;&#1077;&#1083;&#1072;&#1077;&#1096;&#1100;&quest;";
    System.out.println(convAll(test)); // Что тут поделаешь?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чуть поправлю коллегу Daniil Loban. Хотя его код мне нравиться больше

```
String a ="&#1102";
int num = Integer.decode(a.substring(2));
String myString = "U+"+Integer.toHexString(num);
System.out.print(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(myString.substring(2), 16)));
```